# How can I add an if statement to my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

I'm writing a password complexity code... I've done my programme and it says that comparison to true should be`if cond is true:` or `if cond:`, but I couldn't figure it out

this is my programming and I really couldn't add or fix anything in it:

```
import re

print('Please copy the following: password()')
def password():
    print('Make sure that your password has the following rules:')
    print('1. more than 8 characters')
    print('2. has a compination of uppercase and lowercase letters')
    print('3. has digits')
    while True:
        password == input('password:  ')
        if password < 8:
            break
        print('Password must be at least 8 characters')
        if re.search(r'\d', password):
            if re.search(r'\d', password) == True: 
                print('it has a digit')
            else:
                print('Password must contain digits') 
        if re.search(r'[A-Z]', password):
            if re.search(r'[A-Z]', password) == True:
                print('it has uppercase letters')
            else:
                print('Password must contain upper case letters')
        if re.search(r'[a-z]', password):
            if re.search(r'[a-z]', password) == True:
                print('it has lowercase letters')
            else:
                print('Password must contain lowercase letters')
```

if the password doesn't have a lowercase letter, an uppercase letter, there is no digit or it is less than 8 characters it should say so
e.g I expect the output of `abcABC` to say that it Must be at least 8 characters and Must contain digits.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong with your code?

Comment: Just use `if expression` no need for `if expression == True`.

Comment: Okey, I understood nothing about your question...You're already testing if several coditions are true...Have you written that bunch of code?

Comment: it is saying that comparison to true should be ```if cond is true:``` or ```if cond:```

Comment: It is, practically, the very same in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you are getting a `TypeError` in this line here: `if password < 8:`, making you think you don't know how to use if statements.  Really, you don't want to check if password is a number less than 8, that would be a garbage password, you want to check the LENGTH of password like this:

`if len(password) < 8:`

For future reference: posting the EXACT error message (with all the 'junk') is very helpful for us to figure out what is wrong. You should get in the habit of posting the full traceback.

Edit: I also noticed this line `password == input('password:  ')` should only have one equals sign.  The way you have it written, python is checking if they are the same, concluding 'no', then moving to the next line.  With one equals sign you'll set what was input to the password variable.

Comment: yes; i did get a ```TypeError``` in this line. thanx for making it clear for me

Comment: Happy to help! Next time, all this information that comes from your script would help in your question: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#98>", line 1, in <module>
    None < 8
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int`

Answer (score 1):

you don't need `if re.search(r'[A-Z]', password) == True:` just put `if re.search(r'[A-Z]', password)`, because these whether return an `Object` or `None`,
and in Python `if my_variable:` is equivalent to `if my_variable is not None:` depending on your variable data type

Answer (score -1):

You could just use if condition as below:

```
if condition:
    # Do something
```